# Why goto-like functionality in Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

Racket is an advanced functional language. However, it seems that named let constructs allow goto-like functionality and allow spaghetti-like code to be written:

```
(define i 1)
(let mylabel ()
  (set! i (add1 i))
  (println "Doing something...")
  (when (even? i)
    (println "going to mylabel because i is even")
    (mylabel) )
  (when (= 0 (modulo i 3))
    (println "going to mylabel because i is divisible by 3")
    (mylabel) )
  (println "Doing something more ...")
  (when (= i 7)
    (println "going to mylabel because i is 7")
    (mylabel) )
  (when (> i 10)
    (println "ending because i is 10")
    )
  (println i)
  )
```

Is this not goto-like functionality which has been included?

Comment: How is this any more spaghetti-like than regular recursive functions?

Comment: The edited code above may be less like a function and more like a goto.

Comment: First, you cannot "jump" anywhere, but just at the beginning of procedures. And it's equivalent to a goto only if the call is the last statement of the calling procedure. For real goto fun, have a look at continuations.

Comment: You can write Fortran in any language.

Comment: The spaghetti factor depends more on the shared mutable state (that is, `i` and the use of `set!`) than on the named let, in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

Named let is simply a shortcut for defining a recursive function and then calling it right away. If this feature didn't exist, you could just replace `(let mylabel ()` with `(define (mylabel)` and then add `(mylabel)` after the definition to call it. This will behave exactly the same.

So the named let feature does not add any potential for spaghetti-like control flow that wasn't already present with only recursive functions. And since the vast majority of programming languages allow recursive functions, that same potential exists in those languages as well.

Answer (score 2):

Racket and Scheme are not purely functional languages. They are multi paradigm just like Common Lisp and all the Algol languages.

If the language would have been purely functional you wouldn't have the exclamation mark procedures like `set!` and there would have been something like monads in Haskell to make it slightly useful.

A real `goto` would be `call/cc`, which is a requirement for a Scheme that follows one of the reports,  combined with `set!` (or any mutating operator to get the same side effect). With it you can truly make unreadable code:

```
; The following evaluates to (4 3 5)
(let ((a (amb (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7)))
      (b (amb (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7)))
      (c (amb (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7))))

  ; We're looking for dimensions of a legal right
  ; triangle using the Pythagorean theorem:
  (assert (= (* c c) (+ (* a a) (* b b))))

  ; we would like a to be the largest number
  (assert (>= a b))

  ; this must be it then!
  (list a b c))
```

This code is from the excellent Matt Mights [blog post on call/cc](http://matt.might.net/articles/programming-with-continuations--exceptions-backtracking-search-threads-generators-coroutines/). I have left out the non magic so you see only how its used. It does look like magic right? He has [multiple articles](http://matt.might.net/articles/) that might be interesting about continuations, parsing and compilation.

Comment: why unreadable? great looking piece of non-deterministic code! thanks for the link.

Comment: @WillNess I guess you could say it's somewhat understandable what it should do, but how it works is another matter. It blew my mind the first time I saw this.